# Getting linking error while debugging object serialization into xml code in Visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

> ```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall
> ABC::serialize<class boost::archive::xml_oarchive>(class
> boost::archive::xml_oarchive &,unsigned int)"
> (??$serialize@Vxml_oarchive@archive@boost@@@ABC@@AAEXAAVxml_oarchive@archive@boost@@I@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl
> boost::serialization::access::serialize<class
> boost::archive::xml_oarchive,class ABC>(class
> boost::archive::xml_oarchive &,class ABC &,unsigned int)"
> (??$serialize@Vxml_oarchive@archive@boost@@VABC@@@access@serialization@boost@@SAXAAVxml_oarchive@archive@2@AAVABC@@I@Z)   list-boost-xml  C:\Users\neha.gupta\source\repos\list-boost-xml\list-boost-xml.obj  1
> ```

I have created an application that serialize list of ABC into xml. I am using boost library of version 1_76_0 and visual studio 2019.While debugging I am getting above error.
Please help me out why I am getting above error and how to resolve it.
Please find the ABC class below:

```
class ABC
{
public:
    ABC();
    ABC(int x);
    int getData();
    void setdata(int);
    void display();
    
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int /*version*/);
    
    int data;
};
```

Comment: Is `ABC` a class template? Did you try implementing the class template's member functions in a `.cpp` file?

Comment: No ABC is not template class but serialize function is Template function

Comment: I have implemented the serialize function in .cpp file.

Comment: Then just write the implementation directly in the `class` definition you have in your question. `template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int) { ar & data; }` I guess. [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. But, why I am getting error if writing implementation into .cpp file

Comment: Great! The explanation is that a function template is not a function. It must be instantiated first - and it won't be until used. It's not used when you compile your `.cpp` file (unless you have explicitly instantiated it - which is rare). There are more explanations in the link I provided above.